# How do I insert objects into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I insert objects into an array? Here I have a class called HotelRoom which contains getter, setter, and the constructor method.

```
public class HotelRoom {

int roomNumber;
String roomGuest;


public HotelRoom (int room, String guest) {
    roomNumber = room;
    roomGuest = guest;
}

public int getRoom() {
    return roomNumber;
}

public void setRoom() {
    roomNumber = room;
}

public String getName() {
    return roomGuest;
}

public void setName() {
    roomGuest = guest;
}
```

And here I have the main method containing the array initializer and the objects. I've also inserted the objects into the array however, when compiling, the problem arises in the print command and it states: "cannot find symbol - variable HotelRoom". What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Hotel {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    HotelRoom[] rooms = new HotelRoom [5];

    HotelRoom guest1 = new HotelRoom(67, "Harry");
    HotelRoom guest2 = new HotelRoom(98, "Bob");
    HotelRoom guest3 = new HotelRoom(34, "Steven");
    HotelRoom guest4 = new HotelRoom(99, "Larry");
    HotelRoom guest5 = new HotelRoom(103, "Patrick");

    rooms[0] = guest1;
    rooms[1] = guest2;
    rooms[2] = guest3;
    rooms[3] = guest4;
    rooms[4] = guest5;

    System.out.println (HotelRoom);
}
```

}

Comment: You should print `rooms` instead.

Comment: System.out.println (rooms)

Answer (score 4):

This is because `HotelRoom` is a class, not an `Object`. If you have intentions of printing out all of the rooms, perhaps you could try something like:

```
for(final HotelRoom room : rooms)
    System.out.printf("%s in room %d\n", room.getName(), room.getRoom());
```

Or you could override the `toString()` method in `HotelRoom`:

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s in room %d", roomGuest, roomNumber);
}
```

With the overridden `toString()` method, you can now modify your loop to:

```
for(final HotelRoom room : rooms)
   System.out.println(room);
```

Or, if you want:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rooms));
```

Answer (score 0):

HotelRoom is the name of the class. The objects are now in the rooms array. If you are wanting to print out the array, try printing rooms, or a particular place in the array, e.g

```
System.out.println(rooms[0].getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

At first implement `toString()` in the `HotelRoom`:

```
public String toString() {
    return roomNumber + " " + roomGuest;
}
```

And then print the right array:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rooms));
```